# MySQL ordering by possession and not possession of a feature

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have been trying to make a MySQL database query that would retrieve a number of products by tag. I found this task to be rather easy to do, but ordering the result in a correct way seems to be more complicated than I expected.
I have 3 tables product, tag, and tag2product (which relates the id's of the former two) and wrote the following query:

```
SELECT product.id FROM product
LEFT OUTER JOIN tag2product ON product.id=tag2product.product_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tag ON tag2product.tag_id = tag.id
WHERE tag.id=1 OR tag.id=2 OR tag.id=3
GROUP BY product.id;
```

By running this query I receive all unique products that are related with either the first, second or third tag.

What I would like to get is the same result set but in this order:

1. Products that are tagged with **all** 1,2, and 3 and no others.
2. Products that are tagged with **all** 1,2, and 3, **but** have other tags (optionally internally ordered by the number of other tags).
3. Products that are tagged with **any two** of 1,2, and 3 properties and no others.
4. Products that are tagged with **any two** of 1,2, and 3 properties, **but** have other tags (the optional condition of point 2 applies here as well)
5. Products that are tagged with **either one** of 1,2 or 3 properties, and don't have any other tags.
6. Products that are tagged with **either one** of 1,2 or 3 properties, **but** have other tags (same as 2 and 4).

I have a hunch that a similar result could be done by combining a number of unions and sub-queries, but I'm not sure how this can be done.

I really hope that someone can help me with this project or point me to some reading material on the topic. Is it at all possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT products.product_id AS product_id
  , SUM(IF(tag2product.tag_id IN (1,2,3),1,0)) AS matched_tags
  , COUNT(*) AS total_tags
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT product_id
      FROM tag2product
      WHERE tag_id IN (1,2,3)) AS products
JOIN tag2product
  ON products.product_id = tag2product.product_id
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY matched_tags DESC, total_tags;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like a charm. And one more thing, I think it's missing a closing parenthesis after the where clause, right?

Answer (score 1):

First, if you are interested in other tags, you need to change the `where` to a `having` clause.  Otherwise, you will not have that information for the `order by` clause.

The query that you want just has a rather complicated `order by` clause:

```
SELECT product.id
FROM product LEFT OUTER JOIN
     tag2product
     ON product.id=tag2product.product_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
     tag ON tag2product.tag_id = tag.id
WHERE tag.id=1 OR tag.id=2 OR tag.id=3
GROUP BY product.id
HAVING sum(tag.id in (1, 2, 3)) > 0
order by (case when count(distinct case when tag.id in (1, 2, 3) then tag.id end) = 3 and
                    sum(tag.id not in (1, 2, 3)) = 0
               then 1
               when count(distinct case when tag.id in (1, 2, 3) then tag.id end) = 3
               then 2
               when count(distinct case when tag.id in (1, 2, 3) then tag.id end) = 2 and
                    sum(tag.id not in (1, 2, 3)) = 0
               then 3
               when count(distinct case when tag.id in (1, 2, 3) then tag.id end) = 2
               then 4
               when count(distinct case when tag.id in (1, 2, 3) then tag.id end) = 1 and
                    sum(tag.id not in (1, 2, 3)) = 0
               then 5
               when count(distinct case when tag.id in (1, 2, 3) then tag.id end) = 1
               then 6
          end)
```

Comment: Thank you! I sort of went with the answer of AgRizzo because it appeared to me that his solution sorts the final result a little bit better and is easier to generate dynamically in PHP (which I will most probably need to do). Nevertheless, the way you presented also works and provides a lot of control. Thanks again :) And I will read more about the having and in clauses, which I didn't really use up until now.